# Json parsing in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.4

I have a `JSON` string as a result of a query operation . I assign the result to a string literal and then try to read the string. 
I get the below error.

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I get the result in the below format from a query operation with `\n`

```
str = {"start": 0,
  "time": "2015-Mar-15 17:04:33.197042 ::setup Initializing",
  "type": "solar",}

import json
json.loads(str)
```

Should I convert it into a docstring? I'm using `python 3.4`

Comment: Hint: `str` should be a string. What is `type(str)`? Also, don't name things after built-in types or functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example "str" is already an object, so you dont have to parse it. It has already been parsed.

try this:

```
str =
{
    "start": 0,
    "time": "2015-Mar-15 17:04:33.197042 ::setup Initializing",
    "type": "solar",
}
print str["start"]
```

If you had something like this:

```
str = """
{
    "start": 0,
    "time": "2015-Mar-15 17:04:33.197042 ::setup Initializing",
    "type": "solar",
 }"""
```

you could do:

```
import json

json.loads(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `str` is an object, not a string. To make it a `JSON` formatted string use:

```
json.dumps(str)
```